# Creating Hello world event dispatcher(observer) in Magento?

Tags: magento

I am trying to create an event dispatcher in Magento (which should be called after a product gets added to cart).

What I've done so far:

I Googled this and found [this](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/dispatching-before-and-after-events-to-magento-core-actions/) link. I followed the instructions specified in this link. I configured the config.xml file and created a Observer.php filder under mymodule/model folder. But, I can't see any result from this.

(The code for config.xml and Observer.php file that i used in my example can be found under http://goo.gl/O7dBy, my custom module name is Crossdata and package name is MyModule -  am i doing it wrong?)

Any other link with simple helloworld event dispatcher example would be helpful.

Thanks,
Balan

Comment: The reason your code is not showing on SO might be that you're using unusual whitespaces (NO-BREAK SPACEs, 0xC2 0xa0) all over your code. Try to reduce to normal spaces and tabs and it should show up.

Comment: will breaks and spaces affect the code?

Comment: For syntax coloring I could imagine it will. Functional? I don't think so, but never checked that as I never user other whitespace than space and tab to format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your code downloaded from http://goo.gl/O7dBy you define:

```
<events>
    <add_to_cart_after>
        <observers>
            <add_to_cart_after>
                <class>dispatcher/observer</class>
                <method>hookToAddToCartAfter</method>
            </add_to_cart_after>
        </observers>
    </add_to_cart_after>
</events>
```

and define the model alias of `dispatcher` as:

```
<models>
    <dispatcher>
        <class>MyPackage_Crossdata_Dispatcher_Model</class>
    </dispatcher>
</models>
```

The resulting class name would be `MyPackage_Crossdata_Model_Dispatcher_Model_Observer`, but your observer class is named `MyPackage_Crossdata_Dispatcher_Model_Observer`, missing the `Model` in between `Crossdata` and `Dispatcher`.

I'd recommend to drop the whole `dispatcher` models definition above and only use the other model alias `crossdata` which you've already defined in `config.xml`:

```
<crossdata>
    <class>MyPackage_Crossdata_Model</class>
    <resourceModel>crossdata_mysql4</resourceModel>
</crossdata>
```

Then change the event definition to:

```
<add_to_cart_after>
    <class>crossdata/observer</class>
    <method>hookToAddToCartAfter</method>
</add_to_cart_after>
```

Create a file `/app/code/local/MyPackage/Crossdata/Model/Observer.php` and define your observer class in it:

```
class MyPackage_Crossdata_Model_Observer
{
    public function hookToAddToCartAfter($observer)
    {
        // your observer code
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You added a folder for Observer.php, or a file? Can you post the code you wrote for this so we can better help debug with you? That tutorial is about as simple and straightforward as they get.

Comment: My Custom module "Crossdata" is placed under package "MyPackage".. so i copied the Observer.php file under MyPackage/Crossdata/Model/Observer.php.. is this right? For more info i had uploaded both files config.xml and Observer.php file under http://www.fileflyer.com/view/gzhf5Bo

Comment: What i am guessing is either i should be placing the Observer.php file in wrong place or i am messing up with events and models specified in the tutorial in config.xml file.. FYI : all other sections in my config.xml file are working code.

Comment: I can't open your fileflyer stuff. Edit the post with the relevant code so that people in the future can benefit from the question/answer here.

Comment: Since nobody else after today will be able to access that link, please put the relevant code into your post itself.

Answer (score 0):

1. In your `config.xml` the short name given to your blocks and models is `crossdata`. Yet the event uses the alias `dispatcher/observer`, you have not defined a name `dispatcher`. This probably needs to be `crossdata/observer`.
2. The Inchoo example calls it's module `Inchoo_Dispatcher` and the model is `Inchoo_Dispatcher_Model_Observer`. Your module is `MyPackage_Crossdata` which means the alias `crossdata/observer` would try to load `MyPackage_Crossdata_Model_Observer`. But your observer is erroneously called `MyPackage_Crossdata_Dispatcher_Model_Observer`.
3. If your pasted code is not showing here in Stack Overflow either indent it by four spaces or use the <kbd>{}</kbd> button to format it. That is the preferable way to show code.

Comment: He actually *does* define an alias named `dispatcher` at the very bottom of the `config.xml` (at least in the sources of [http://goo.gl/O7dBy](http://goo.gl/O7dBy)), but it's not clear whether he really wants the `dispatcher` alias to be used, or the `crossdata` one, because his class is named `MyPackage_Crossdata_Dispatcher_Model_Observer`.