# How to create event dispatcher in magento?

Tags: php, xml, magento

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Creating Hello world event dispatcher(observer) in Magento?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5726230/creating-hello-world-event-dispatcherobserver-in-magento)

Hi ,

In my Mage website i am in a situation to perform a set of tasks after a product being added to the shopping cart... i tried to create an event dispatcher, but not succeeded in it.

Can anyone give me info about step by step implementation of event dispatcher or any helpful link?

Thanks,

Balan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Step 1**: define your module in `/app/etc/module/Mycompany_Observer.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Mycompany_Observer>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <depends>
                <Mage_Core />
            </depends>
        </Mycompany_Observer>
    </modules>
</config>
```

**Step 2**: define your configuration in `/app/code/local/Mycompany/Observer/etc/config.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Mycompany_Observer>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Mycompany_Observer>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <myobserver>
                <class>Mycompany_Observer_Model</class>
            </myobserver>
        </models>
    </global>
    <frontend>
        <events>
            <add_to_cart_after>
                <observers>
                    <my_unique_identifier>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>myobserver/observer</class>
                        <method>myAddToCartAfter</method>
                    </my_unique_identifier>
                </observers>
            </add_to_cart_after>
        </events>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

**Step 3**: define your observer in `/app/code/local/Mycompany/Observer/Model/Observer.php`:

```
class Mycompany_Observer_Model_Observer extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
{
    public function myAddToCartAfter($oObserver)
    {
        var_dump($oObserver->getData());
        die('stop');
    }
}
```